# With threadsafe off, Appengine still routes more than one request to an instance

Tags: google-app-engine

The GAE doc says "By default, App Engine sends requests serially to a given web server. If you are using the Python 2.7 runtime, you can configure App Engine to send multiple, parallel requests by adding the threadsafe: true element to the header of app.yaml."

Now I set the 'threadsafe: false' in my app.yaml. But seems it doesn't work. I can still see two requests are routed into two handlers of my instance. I suppose with threadsafe off, only one request would be passed to my server at a time, no matter to which handler. Is that true? Is this a GAE bug or something I do wrong in my codes?

BTW: my codes locate at : https://code.google.com/p/webrtc-samples/source/browse/trunk/apprtc/

Comment: How do you check that there are two parallel requests happening?

Comment: even you saw there are more than one request per instance, it doesn't mean these requests were processed at the same time.